# How to allow agents to connect to Jenkins controller without "-secret" jnlp option?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

Yesterday, my Jenkins controller (v 1.646, linux debian Jessie 8.3) was working and several agents was connecting on it via the jnlp command:

```
java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://myhost:8080/computer/bob-pc.local/slave-agent.jnlp
```

Now I guess something changed (war update ? plugin update ? security option changed ?) because now my agents cant connect anymore since the jnlp command is now :

```
java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://myhost:8080/computer/bob-pc.local/slave-agent.jnlp -secret rt435te435a208c7201d99f7b1e5dd9c044da86d12efd8527
```

The `-secret ...` part of the command is new and I cant figure out which change added this option.

**How to allow agents to connect to Jenkins controller without "-secret" jnlp option ?**

Comment: Have you checked *Enable security* in *Manage Jenkins > Global Security*? You can try to turn it off.

Comment: I switched "Configure Global Security > Authorization" to "Anyone can do anything" and it worked ! Best approach globally is to switch all security off and then reactivate them one by one.  Post this as an answer if u want.

Comment: Try if mainframer's answer works first, as he indeed has a point in not having security enabled should only be used in rare cases as it poses high risks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This credential behavior is controlled by [Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Authorization+Strategy+Plugin), this plugin is shipped with jenkins by default.

If you are the jenkins administrator, you can turn this off by following these steps:

> Manage Jenkins -->Configure Global Security-->Access Control-->Authorization

Either in **Matrix-based security** or **Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy**, make sure you you have checked the `Connect` options of Slave for **Anonymous** role.

[image]

Comment: "Matrix-based security" was activated but then I desactivated it : Manage Jenkins -->Configure Global Security-->Access Control-->Authorization ==> "Logged-in users can do anything". Jenkins restarted, nothing changed !

Comment: You should either activate "Matrix-based security"  or activate "Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy" , not "Logged-in users can do anything". And in addition, no need to restart jenkins.

Comment: it worked ! It activated "Matrix Authorization Strategy" and followed the mainframer tip.